# How to find an object in an List of object and save by its ID - SpringBoot

Tags: java, list, spring-boot

I have a List of Book objects that contain `bookId`.

I have to pass that List of Book objects and save each object in its row in database.

List looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "bookId": 2
    },
    {
        "bookId": 3
    },
    {
        "bookId": 2
    },
    {
        "bookId": 3
    }
]
```

Could someone guide me how the code should look like?

I started something like this:

```
public void addMultipleRents(List<RentDto> rentDtoList, long userId){
        List<Rent> rentList = Arrays.asList(modelMapper.map(rentDtoList, Rent.class));

        RentDto rentDto = new RentDto();
        
        User user = userRepository.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new UserNotFoundException("User with id: " + 
        rentDto.getUserId() + " is not found"));
         
        List<Rent> rent = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Rent r  : rentList){
            r.setRentStart(LocalDateTime.now());
            r.setUser(user);
            r.setBook(book);
            rent.add(r);
        }

        rentRepository.saveAll(rentList);
}
```

**Rent.java**

```
public class Rent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private LocalDateTime rentStart;
    private LocalDateTime rentEnd;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Book book;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

}
```

**RentDto.java**

public class RentDto {

```
private Long rentId;

private Long userId;

private Long bookId;

private String userFirstName;

private String userLastName;

private String bookTitle;

private LocalDateTime rentStart;

private LocalDateTime RentEnd;
```

}

But I am getting error for `r.setBook(book);`:

```
The given id must not be null!
```

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell without seeing the relevant parts of your code but I guess that `book` is either null or refers to an entity that doesn't have any id. Also why are you converting from `rentDtoList` to `rentList` and additionally iterate over `rentList` to set more values? Why don't you do that in one go (assuming there's not more to `Rent`)?

Comment: Yes, that is true. I should get that `id` from a list of objects where each object has its own `bookId`. But I don't know how to do it. Yes I do have a `Rent.java` I added it to question. When I iterate through `List<Rent>` how can I get that `bookId` to save it to database as book? Because my `Rent.java` has `Book book` and `User user `property.

Comment: Well, you know how to get a single user by id so what's the problem with getting a single book by the id set in the dto? It won't yield the best performance but it should get you started. Once that works try getting books for multiple ids.

Comment: Because `userId` I am passing as parameter and `bookId` I should get from `List` I am passing as parameter. Is it? But I don't know how :/

Comment: Well, you could iterate over the list of dtos and get the book id from each of those individually for a start.

Comment: That was why I was passing List of `RentDto` because it consists `bookId`. I understand that in theory but could you maybe give me some code example? :)

Comment: Well, it could be as simple as `for(RentDto dto : rentDtoList) { Book book = bookRepository.getBookById( dto.getBookId() ); /*then use the book here*/ }`. If you don'T have a `BookRepository` yet or need more information in your dtos then add that. :)

Comment: Okay I added it see my question update. Now when I have `bookId` in for loop as `dto` now what?  :)

Comment: Well, the rest should be fairly obvious: create a `Rent` entity for each rental, set user and book as well as the start date, and finally save them.

Comment: Do you mean in for loop like this  `for(Rent r  : rentList){
            r.setRentStart(LocalDateTime.now());
            r.setUser(user);
            r.setBook(book);
        }` this again undelines book red

Comment: Not exactly. You should _create_ a `Rent` entity from the dto, get the book for the book id and set it via `setBook()` etc. - One question here: I have the impression that it wasn't you who introduced the repositories, created `modelMapper` etc., was it? All those questions give the impression that you are quite a beginner and might be in way over your head already, is that impression correct?

Comment: Mateee :) all that is true I  am a huge beginner but thanks to YOU code is working. Check my question update. Can you add answer, so I can accept and up vote you :) Thank you so so so much!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the trail of comments:

Instead of relying on `modelMapper` (whatever the class is) you could iterate over the list of DTOs yourself and create a `Rent` entity for each of those. You then put them into a list and save that list as you're doing already.

The pseudo code for this could be something like this (simplified):

```
User user = userRepo.getById(userId); //get the user for all rentals

List<Rent> rentList = new ArrayList<>(rentDtos.size()); //you already know the list size you're expecting
for( RentDTO dto : rentDtos) {
  Book book = bookRepo.getById( dto.getBookId() ); //the book for the one rental
  Rent rent = new Rent(); //create a new rent
  ... //set user, book and rent time here
  rentList.add(rent);
}

rentRepository.saveAll(rentList);
```

Note that this (pseudo) code isn't meant to be compilable, fast or to handle all possible errors but to get you started.

One obvious improvement would be to first collect a set of book ids, load all books for those ids (e.g. as a `Map<Long, Book>`) and then get the books to assignto the `Rent` entities from that map. I'll leave that as an exercise for you though.

One final advice: since you're a beginner you should first get a good grasp of the basics before getting too deep into complex frameworks such as Spring etc. Those frameworks make use of concepts like dependency injection, object-relational mapping etc. which would be too hard to understand correctly if you're still missing the basics.